# What is the internal representation of timestamp values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a **.dat** file that represents a Table in a database and has a particular column for `timestamp` values. Now the values are stored in the following way: -

`978302039`

I'm required to copy all the elements into another table, but I'm not sure if the column containing these values should be of `int` or `timestamp`. As far as I know, we store `timestamp` values in the following format: -

`1000:09:12 00:00:00`

But these values stored here don't look anything like that. Is there any internal representation of `timestamp` values?

Answer (score 0):

Per [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

> MySQL recognizes `TIMESTAMP` values in these formats:
>
> As a number in either `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` format,
>   provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example,
>   19830905132800 and 830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05
>   13:28:00'.

With that, the value you have posted looks like a invalid `timestamp` to me.

Comment: But the numbers in my file supposedly representing `timestamp` values are small in the sense that it has less number of digits. Could it be the representation of time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

`978302039` looks like a unix timestamp in seconds. You can convert it to MySQLs DATETIME with the [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(978302039)
```

will return something like

```
2000-12-31 22:33:59
```

The exact value depends on the timezone configuration of your server.