# What is the result of DateTime operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried the following SQL query.

```
select start_time, end_time, end_time-start_time from orders
```

This printed the following output.

```
start_time          |end_time             |end_time-start_time
...
2019-11-29 15:55:54 | 2019-12-01 15:59:00 | 72000346
...
```

I have no idea what the result means.
I know that we can use *TIMESTAMPDIFF* to calculate difference between two datetime.
Does anyone know what the result means?

Comment: I suppose this query ran by using `FRAC_SECOND` as unit for `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function on MySQL DB with version prior to 5.5 . There exists no such unit for `TIMESTAMPDIFF` on DB ver. 5.5+

Comment: I think that it's a bug when these timestamps are substracted, and give an unclear values, probably a left-over from this  [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33834) ?

Comment: Short answer: nothing useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an unnerving tendency to treat date/time values as numbers or strings, rather than as date/times.  Often, this is not important because the values are readily converted to date/times.

But, for the values in the your question, the representations are:

```
 2019-12-01 15:59:00 --> 20191201155900
 2019-11-29 15:55:54 --> 20191129155554
```

The result you are getting is `20191201155900 - 20191129155554`.

This happens because `-` is an operator on numbers, and numbers have a higher preference.  It can also happen with `+`, but that can be fixed by adding `interval` to the expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  start_time,
  end_time, 
  '0000000000000000000'+end_time   as exp1,
  '0000000000000000000'-start_time as exp2,
  '0000000000000000000'+end_time - '0000000000000000000'-start_time      as exp3
from orders;
```

output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
| start_time          | end_time            | exp1           | exp2            | exp3     |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
| 2019-11-29 15:55:54 | 2019-12-01 15:59:00 | 20191201155900 | -20191129155554 | 72000346 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

[What is the internal representation of timestamp values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597630/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-timestamp-values-in-mysql)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html